# Is there a name for two player games in which the payoffs live in the set $[0,1]$ and add to $1$?

Tags: logic, terminology, game-theory

A two player game in which the payoffs add to $0$ is called a zero-sum game. These are often described as games where one person's gain is another player's loss. However, this is a bad description, because there are non-zero sum games where one player's win is another player's loss. For example, suppose we play a game to decide how to split a pie. The better I play, the worse off my opponent is, and the better they play, the worse off I am. But it's not zero sum. Furthermore, if we think of the total utility of the pie as $1$, then the basic facts about this game are:

- All payoffs are positive or zero.
- No matter the outcome, the sum of my payoff and the opponents payoff will always be $1$.

> **Question.** Is there a name for such games?

Comment: How about "one-sum game"?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, note that there's also a condition that all payoffs are positive or zero. Also, note that I'm looking for standard terminology, not reasonable suggestions for new terminology.

Comment: _Then there isn't one!_

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, how do you know?

Comment: Because your conditions are too specific.

Comment: @ParclyTaxel, you're being silly. This is like saying: "I know there's no terminology for a signed measure that takes values in the set $[0,1]$ and maps the whole outcome space to $1$, because the conditions are too specific." In fact, there is terminology for such things, they're called probability measures.

Comment: I know, right? Apparently though you would be looking for _cake cutting_ (as in fair cake-cutting, etc.)

Comment: I don't claim to know for sure, but I would be surprised if this had a name.  Although it's not a zero-sum game, it's equivalent to one from the game-theoretic point of view.  In effect you and your opponent are both being paid $1/2$ to play a zero-sum game.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, nice observation.

Answer (score 1):

These games are called **constant-sum** games.

However, as @Robert Israel points out, these are equivalent to zero-sum games. Hence a Google search for "constant-sum games" leads to the Wikipedia article for zero-sum games. Also, the class of constant-sum games is, of course, larger than the class you describe, as they only require one of the restrictions you make.